# How to handle large matrices and matrix multiplication in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to execute a matrix multiplication which has the following scheme:

```
C = np.dot(np.dot(sparse.csr_matrix(np.double(A).transpose()),sparse.spdiags(B,0,Ngrid,Ngrid)), sparse.csr_matrix(np.double(A)))
```

Thus, I want to transpose matrix A, which lead to a N x M matrix with M>>N and multiply with the diagonal matrix which is a M x M matrix. B is the „main diagonal“. The resulting matrix (N x M) should be multiplied with matrix A (M x N) and lead to the N x N matrix C.

The error appears is the following:

```
<2000x921600 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1843066024 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

As the final matrix is N x N, I want to have this matrix as a numpy array. How you see, I try to make the matrix in the mid as a sparsity diagonal matrix which works well. But, I cant understand why Python need this insane large matrix with 1843066024 elements to conduct the multiplication.

Do you have some ideas and/or explanation why this problem appears?

Comment: What are the shapes of the matricies you are multiplying?

Comment: full error with traceback please.

Comment: What's the approximate sparsity of the matrices?

Comment: @TomMcLean It varies. For example I got N = 921600 and M = 3000

Comment: @hpaulj A is not a sparsity matrix, but the matrix in the mid is an diagonal matrix.

Comment: If `` is not sparse, don't use parse calcultions.  It doesn't matter if the other is diagonal

Comment: I strongly advise you to check the need to create such a HUGE output matrix (with 921600 x 921600 = 849_346_560_000 items -- 6320 GiB). Regarding the next computations based on it, it may not be useful to generate it. If you really want it, then be prepared to a significantly more complex code to be written (due to tiling) and a very long computation time.

Comment: You haven't given a traceback, but it looks lilke this step is raising the memory error: `sparse.csr_matrix(np.double(A).transpose())`.  The shape 2000x921600 is consistent with the N,M you've given, and 1843066024 is close to 2000*921600.  A sparse matrix from such a dense array will occupy 2 to 3x as much memory as the dense array itself.  I don't think it's even gotten to the point of doing any matrix mulltiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `B` is diagonal, you don't need to use sparse to save memory.  You can do the calculation with a 1d array, just the diagonal values.

I'll demonstrate with small dimensions, where making a full `B` is doesn't cause problems.  Others can test this with large dimensions.

```
In [5]: A = np.arange(24).reshape(3,8)
In [7]: B = np.diag(np.arange(8))
In [8]: B.shape
Out[8]: (8, 8)
```

The double matmul:

```
In [10]: A@B@A.T
Out[10]: 
array([[  784,  1904,  3024],
       [ 1904,  4816,  7728],
       [ 3024,  7728, 12432]])
```

The equivalent `einsum`:

```
In [12]: np.einsum('ij,jk,lk',A,B,A)
Out[12]: 
array([[  784,  1904,  3024],
       [ 1904,  4816,  7728],
       [ 3024,  7728, 12432]])
```

The 1d diagonal of `B`:

```
In [15]: b = np.diag(B)
```

A broadcasted multiplication does the same thing as the matmul:

```
In [17]: np.allclose(A*b,A@B)
Out[17]: True
In [18]: np.allclose(A*b@A.T,A@B@A.T)
Out[18]: True
```

Expressing that with `einsum`:

```
In [19]: np.einsum('ij,j,lj',A,b,A)
Out[19]: 
array([[  784,  1904,  3024],
       [ 1904,  4816,  7728],
       [ 3024,  7728, 12432]])
```

Some comparative times:

```
In [20]: timeit np.einsum('ij,j,lj',A,b,A)
10.6 µs ± 22.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
In [21]: timeit np.einsum('ij,jk,lk',A,B,A)
15.2 µs ± 13.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
In [22]: timeit A@B@A.T
7.26 µs ± 20.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
In [23]: timeit A*b@A.T
8.17 µs ± 12.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

For `einsum` the 'condensed' version is faster.  With `matmul` the full diagonal is marginally faster.

But with large arrays where creating a full `B` might a problem, using `b` might be faster.  Also it's been observed in other SO that iterations on smaller arrays can be faster, due to better memory handling.

```
np.array([A[i,:]*b@A.T for i in range(3)])
```

Comment: The solution A*b@A.T works very well. This is equivalent to the solution in Matlab which is double(A)'*spdiags(B,0,N,N)*double(A) and do not result in the error message due to full memory. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You're doing this... overly complicated. Here's a straightforward path for `M >> N` (you're inconsistent on that).

```
import numpy as np

B = sparse.spdiags(B,0,Ngrid,Ngrid)) # [M x M] sparse
A = np.ndarray(..., dtype=float)     # [M x N] dense

C = A.T @ B   # [N x M] dense
C = C @ A     # [N x N] dense
```

`C` is then the array that you want. None of your intermediate products are `M x M`. If you still have memory problems, you either need to get more memory, or you need to chunk your problem into smaller pieces on your `m` axis and calculate them piecewise.

Comment: This implementation is still not very efficient. That being said, the main issue is that N=921600 and thus C takes 6320 GiB of RAM which is to big for any computer (not to mention the 5 million-billion operations required to do that resulting in >1h of computation)... This is clearly not reasonable. So the actual question is why the OP would do that in the first place.

Comment: I assume that's `M`, not `N` (as `M` is noted to be the large axis in the question), but you are correct that if `N` is 1e6 rows the order of operations should be changed to not make any `N x N` products.

Comment: The OP gave conflicting informations: "M>>N" and "N = 921600 and M = 3000"... Anyway, if N is small and M big, then you can replace the first matrix multiplication by `C = (A.T * B[None,:])` which should be much faster (sparse matrices are pretty slow to operate on).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant that M=921600.